# Problem with validating XML file with XSD schema file

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have a XML schema XSD file I want to use to either validate XML files or to generate class file from it.

The XSD schema can be seen at [XSD schema file](https://static.anaf.ro/static/10/Anaf/Informatii_R/Ro_SAFT_Schema_v247_20230306.xsd)

But in both cases I get the following error

> Invalid particle derivation by restriction - 'Derived element
> 'mfp:anaf:dgti:d406t:declaratie:v1:Name' is not a valid restriction of
> base element 'mfp:anaf:dgti:d406t:declaratie:v1:Name' according to
> Elt:Elt -- NameAndTypeOK.'

The problem might be related to the first line of the XSD, because neither the string `mfp:anaf:dgti:d406:declaratie:v1` nor `mfp:anaf:dgti:d406t:declaratie:v1` appear in any otherr place of the XSD document

```
<xs:schema 
  xmlns="mfp:anaf:dgti:d406:declaratie:v1" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:doc="urn:schemas-OECD:schema-extensions:documentation"
  xmlns:nsSAFT="mfp:anaf:dgti:d406t:declaratie:v1" 
  targetNamespace="mfp:anaf:dgti:d406t:declaratie:v1" 
  elementFormDefault="qualified" 
  attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
  version="2.4.7" id="SAF-T">
```

The XML I'm trying to validate is show below (partial, just the relevant part)

```
<nsSAFT:AuditFile 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="urn:StandardAuditFile-Taxation-Financial:RO Romanian_SAF-T_Financial_Schema_v_2_3.xsd" 
  xmlns:nsSAFT="mfp:anaf:dgti:d406t:declaratie:v1">
    <nsSAFT:Header>
      <nsSAFT:AuditFileVersion>2.0</nsSAFT:AuditFileVersion
      <nsSAFT:AuditFileCountry>RO</nsSAFT:AuditFileCountry
      <nsSAFT:AuditFileDateCreated>2023-05-23</nsSAFT:AuditFileDateCreated
      <nsSAFT:SoftwareVersion>1.0</nsSAFT:SoftwareVersion
    </nsSAFT:Header>
</nsSAFT:AuditFile>
```

Even if I generate the XML with first line as below (no "t" in the xmlns:nsSAFT attribute), I get the same validation error

```
<nsSAFT:AuditFile 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="urn:StandardAuditFile-Taxation-Financial:RO Romanian_SAF-T_Financial_Schema_v_2_3.xsd" 
  xmlns:nsSAFT="mfp:anaf:dgti:d406:declaratie:v1">
```

If I try to generate the class code using xsd.exe from the XSD file I get the error below

Any idea what the problem is?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong with your schema and we can't tell you what it is without seeing the schema.

There is no problem with your XML source document.

There is nothing wrong with the namespace declarations at the top of the schema. (The fact that you are worried about them tells us, however, that you are very unfamiliar with this technology.)

Reading between the lines, we can tell you didn't write this schema because you don't understand the technology well enough to do so. So someone else wrote the schema. Who was that? Perhaps they tested it using a different schema processor and it worked with that one. Perhaps they didn't test it at all. You have two possible lines of investigation: debug the fault in the schema, or investigate how you came to be using a broken schema.

*LATER*

Thank you for linking to the schema. The Saxon schema processor agrees with the processor you are using that the schema is invalid. The detailed error message is:

```
Error on line 2160 of Ro_SAFT_Schema_v247_20230306.xsd:
   The content model of the complex type
  Q{mfp:anaf:dgti:d406t:declaratie:v1}CompanyHeaderStructure is not a valid restriction of
  the content model of the type Q{mfp:anaf:dgti:d406t:declaratie:v1}CompanyStructure. The
  definition of element Name differs between the restricted type and the base type. The type
  of the element in the restricted content model is not validly derived from the type of the
  corresponding element in the base content model. The type
  Q{mfp:anaf:dgti:d406t:declaratie:v1}SAFmiddle2textType is not validly derived from the
  type Q{mfp:anaf:dgti:d406t:declaratie:v1}SAFlongtextType
```

I can only suggest that you raise this as a problem with the authors of the schema. My guess would be that they have only tested it with one schema processor - probably the Microsoft one.

The XSD 1.0 specification does have some problems in its rules for defining when one type is a valid restriction of another, which is why there are some variations between implementations in this area.

Comment: Yes, I'm not very familiar with XML. I'm using it mostly as a vehicle to exchange between systems, and to validate it against schemas provided  by those systems. This schema is created by financial authority, and is needed to generate financial audit file that needs to be uploaded to national financial authority.  I added in the main post the link to the actual schema XSD.